# Linking the Tab View to its file

Tags: swift, xcode, tabview

I am trying to experiment with Tab Views in swift. I've created a tab in the StoryBoard and linked it up correctly. I also set up the file by selecting the Cocoa Touch Class and the UIViewController option. My question is how do I link the file with the view so that it works like how the others do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the storyboard and select the Tab view controller on your storyboard. In the identity inspector set the class to Your ViewController class.